# Fast macro expansion

Tags: macros, preprocessor, interpreter, c-preprocessor

Currently I work on my C-Interpreter. Now I want to optimize a little bit. What is the fastest way to expand a macro? For example: I go through my whole code and find a object-like macro. From this point in the source-file, I have to go through the complete translation-unit (not only the current file) and have to search for identifiers with the macro name and replace it with the replacement-list. If I have 20 macros, I have to scan 20 times. That's a fatal performance killer. Does anyone know how other preprocessors handle a macro expansion?

Comment: Take a look at how preprocessor is tied into a lexer in Clang. You don't even need a separate preprocessing step this way - it will take place during tokenisation.

Answer (score 1):

For such lookups, you could use *HashMap*, or *Map*, or *Binary Tree*.

HashMap is easier to use, and if you using C++, you could use [a STL hash_map](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/hash_map.html)